# Is there a way to automagically import static variables like when importing objects in neovim with jdtls and nvim-cmp

Tags: java, neovim, nvim-lspconfig

I have set up neovim to have all of the features that I want from intelij and none of the ones I don't, or at least I thought so until a couple days ago I realized that when I reference a static variable from another file the lsp freaks out and it won't complete it for me.
This means that I have to manually import the variables which is kinda annoying.

I know this comes off as a rant more than a question, but I really don't mean it that way.

any help is appreciated and if none is given I understand

I use jdtls as my lsp client